# Как эффективнее обрабатывать большой файл по кускам Windows C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Есть файл во много раз больший оперативной памяти. Собираюсь реализовать алгоритм, который загружает часть файла, помещающуюся в оперативную память и там обрабатывает. Как сделать это с максимальной эффективностью по времени на C++ под Windows?
Mapping файла на оперативную память?
Как определить максимальный (!) размер куска, который поместится в оперативную память?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751873/how-to-read-huge-file-in-c

Comment: Ничего особенного, в С++ как раз реализованы алгоритмы побитового чтения. Можно создать буферный массив и считывать в него. Целесообразно ставить буфер от килобайта (желательно - от десятков килобайт, но зависит от данных)

Answer (score 0):

многие бенчмарки показывают, что максимальную скорость накопитель демонстрирует, если читать блоками по 128 Кб и выше. в этих же тестах максимальный размер блока используется 8 Мб.

исходя из этого, если использовать блок в 128 Кб или больше, то достаточно просто объявить переменную-массив необходимого размера, например 8 Мб, (все примеры кода привожу для использования в Visual C++ и WinAPI), читать из файла кусками в этот массив и производить необходимую обработку:

```
// объявление массива на 8 Мб
BYTE pBuffer [8 * 1024 * 1024];

// объявление переменной для хэндла файла
HANDLE hFile;

// объявление переменной для получения количества прочитанных байт
DWORD dwHaveRead;

// объявление переменной для получения результата функции чтения файла
BOOL blResult;

// открытие заведомо существующего файла с доступом только на чтение,
// общим доступом тоже только на чтение и с указанием для ОС, что файл
// будет последовательно считываться (это необходимо для лучшего кэширования)
hFile = CreateFile ("...", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

// проверка, что файл успешно открыт
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  // цикл чтения файла кусками по 8 Мб
  do
  {
    // чтение файла
    blResult = ReadFile (hFile, pBuffer, sizeof (pBuffer), &dwHaveRead, NULL);

    // некий код обработки считанных данных из файла
    ...
  } while (blResult && (dwHaveRead == sizeof (pBuffer)));

  // закрытие файла
  CloseHandle (hFile);
}
```

но сразу скажу, что так делать не очень хорошо, так как Windows выделяет сразу необходимое количество памяти, для размещения всех переменных в ней, которые будут (или не будут) использоваться в данном приложении на всЁ время, пока это приложение запущено. понятное дело, что сегодня в компьютерах установлено по несколько Гб памяти, на фоне которой эти жалкие 8 Мб погоды не сделают, но лучше для таких больших массивов память выделять динамически, а потом, когда эти массивы уже не нужны, можно освобождать память. тем самым экономнее использовать оперативную память:

```
// определение своей константы
#define BUFFERSIZE 8 * 1024 * 1024

// объявление переменной для получения указателя на выделенную память
LPVOID pBuffer;

// объявление переменной для хэндла файла
HANDLE hFile;

// объявление переменной для получения количества прочитанных байт
DWORD dwHaveRead;

// объявление переменной для получения результата функции чтения файла
BOOL blResult;

// динамическое выделение памяти нужного объЁма
pBuffer = VirtualAlloc (NULL, BUFFERSIZE, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

// проверка, что память успешно выделена
if (pBuffer != NULL)
{
  // открытие заведомо существующего файла с доступом только на чтение,
  // общим доступом тоже только на чтение и с указанием для ОС, что файл
  // будет последовательно считываться (это необходимо для лучшего кэширования)
  hFile = CreateFile ("...", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

  // проверка, что файл успешно открыт
  if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    // цикл чтения файла кусками
    do
    {
      // чтение файла
      blResult = ReadFile (hFile, pBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, &dwHaveRead, NULL);

      // некий код обработки считанных данных из файла
      ...
    } while (blResult && (dwHaveRead == BUFFERSIZE)));

    // закрытие файла
    CloseHandle (hFile);
  }

  // освобождение выделенной памяти
  VirtualFree (pBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
}
```

Comment: а зачем использовать `VirtualAlloc` ? Почему не new/calloc/malloc? Или потому, что не смогли выделить 8мб на стеке?

Comment: Я хочу загрузить блок как можно большего размера, но при этом чтобы он влезал в память (подкачка не использовалась, или использовалась как можно меньше)

Comment: 8 мегабайт - это сейчас совсем не о чем. Вот лет 40 назад - это был огромный размер. И если нужно, Ваша выделенная память пойдет в подкачаку сразу (ну если это не драйвер с особой памятью).

Comment: @KoVadim, я указал, что код для WinAPI, следовательно я использую функции WinAPI. функция new использует внутри себя функцию malloc.

Comment: @KoVadim, если необходимо выделить на стеке, то можно использовать первый вариант кода, где объявляется массив на 8 Мб. винда выделяет на стеке достаточно памяти для хранения всех локальных переменных.

Comment: по умолчанию, в винде (если ничего не трогать), размер стека равен 1 мб. Вместить 8мб в стеке в этом случае немного сложновато. Поэтому, первый вариант без подстройки размера стека использовать немного сложновато.

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня стоит VS 2015, параметры проекта особо не ковырял (только оптимизацию по производительности сделал). всЁ остальное, как говорится, по умолчанию.
хотя когда-то давно натыкался на рубеж этот в 1 Мб. попробовал сейчас вот. массив на 8 Мб без проблем даЁт объявить, компилирует без ошибок, даже запускается и выполняется код без ошибок.
где какой параметр в VS отвечает за этот рубеж - без понятия, не изучал этот момент.

Comment: оно то компилируется. и даже запускается, но потом падает с stack overflow.

Comment: @KoVadim, забавно... у меня почему-то не падает.

Comment: запускаете dumpbin /headers бинарь.exe и ищите "100000 size of stack reserve" - это размер (в хексе) стека, которое выделено Вашему приложению. В данном случае там 1 мб

Comment: @slou_pc, чтобы выделенный кусок памяти во втором примере не попадал в файл подкачки, надо добавить код:

1. `VirtualLock (pBuffer, BUFFERSIZE);` перед строкой открытия файла;
2. `VirtualUnlock (pBuffer, BUFFERSIZE);` перед строкой освобождения памяти.